# getting last record of a cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

If I have a cursor `cur`  which contain these records

```
DEPTNO ENAME  ORD   CNT                        
10     KING   1      3                      
10     CLARK  2      3                      
10     MILLER 3      3                      
20     JONES  1      5
```

I get my cursor record like this :

```
FOR i IN cur LOOP
  --Process
END LOOP;
```

Now I need to enhance my process and do a check, if the value of CNT column of the **last record** is equal to 5 I don't need to navigate into this cursor.

Is there a way to directly get the last record of the cursor to test CNT column without looping ?

Comment: Write a separate query to determine the condition, or come up with some way to add a constraint such as "where not exists (< some subquery to determine if val = 5 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  A cursor is a pointer to a program that executes the query.  You can only fetch from the cursor.  Oracle itself has no idea what the last row the cursor will return until you attempt to fetch a row and find there are no more rows to return.

You could, of course, modify the query so that the `CNT` of the last row is returned in a separate column (assuming that you have some way to order the rows so that the "last row" is a meaningful concept).